# Allow access to private dependencies before install

Tags: travis-ci

I have a github project being tracked by Travis.

Currently, I have a new dependency, which is a private repo.

For now, I just need to use the simple `Deploy Key` approach.

This is my understanding of the steps that are needed:

- generate the public/private ssh key  pair
- encrypt it using travis cli
- ship the encrypted `key.enc` to the repository

Then the CLI enlights us with command we can use to decrypt the file:

```
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_X_key -iv $encrypted_Y_iv -in key.enc -out key -d
```

I can decrypt the key now.

But how do I add it to the ssh-agent at build time?

Answer (score 0):

This is the required step to add the key before installing the private dependencies:

```
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_X_key -iv $encrypted_Y_iv -in .travis/key.enc -out .travis/key -d
  - chmod 600 .travis/key
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - ssh-add .travis/key
```